# How to enable Javascript in Jade template to access DOM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, pug

I want to draw on a HTML5 canvas in a Jade template.  To do this, I need to use some Javascript like this:

```
function tileAllCanvases(){  
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    //draw things
}
```

My Jade template is:

```
doctype html
html 
    head
        title = title
    body
        canvas(id="canvas",width="7000",height="4000",style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;")
        script. 
            !{drawing.tileAllCanvases()}
```

The `document.getElementById("canvas")` call gives me the error `document is not defined`.  I think this is happening because Jade is rendering the HTML server-side and therefore it can't access the DOM.  So I guess I need to have this code called client-side.  I tried adding the following to my Jade template:

```
script(src='../main.js', type='text/javascript')
```

instead of the `script.` call, where `main.js` is a file that, among other things, calls the canvas drawing code, but this caused an `ERROR 404 NOT FOUND` when I opened the page client-side.  Maybe because the client-side code is looking for `'../main.js'` and of course it can't find it because that file is on the server.

So...what can I do to draw on a `canvas` element using code that's passed to Jade?  Or, more generally, how do I draw on a `canvas` element in a page that I'm generating via a server-side rendering engine?

Edit: looks like I can use [node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) to create a canvas-like object server-side, but I don't quite understand how to then include this data in the page that I'm rendering.  I see that I can save the canvas object as a PNG and then stream it, but that makes things much more complicated because now I have to handle storage of these dynamically generated files...hopefully there's an easier way to include the `node-canvas` data in my page?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution for this using node-canvas.  Basically it works like this:

```
const Canvas = require('canvas');

function drawOnCanvas(data,width,height){  
    let canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(width,height);
    drawThings(data,canvas);  //code for drawThings() is the same as with the DOM version of Canvas
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

Call this function before rendering the page, so that `dataURL` can be exposed to Jade as a parameter:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Drawing = require('../drawing.js');

const drawing = new Drawing();
const dataURL = drawing.drawOnCanvas(someData,100,100);

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('drawing', { 
        title: 'Drawing',
        dataURL: dataURL
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And then use `dataURL` to create the bitmap in the template.

```
doctype html
html 
    head
        title= title
    body
        img(src=dataURL)
```